# How to remove duplicates from stack?

Tags: c

**TASK:** Let's say there is an integer stack S with M elements. Give the algorithm that will remove all those numbers from stack S that appear two or more times. (write the task using C/C++)

**NOTE:** We are not allowed to use `std::stack` to solve this task.

First of all I decided to use C language, and this is stack implementation I use.

```
int* stack = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
int size = 10;
int sp = -1;

bool isempty() {
    return (sp == -1);
}

bool isfull() {
    return (sp == size - 1);
}

void push(int x) {
    if (isfull()) {
        printf("Full!");
    }
    else {
        sp++;
        stack[sp] = x;
    }
}

int pop() {
    int x;
    if (isempty()) {
        printf("Empty!");
    }
    else {
        x = stack[sp];
        sp--;
    }
    return x;
}

void peek() {
    if (!isempty()) {
        printf("%d", stack[sp]);
    }
}

void clear() {
    while (!isempty()) {
        pop();
    }
}

void print() {
    if (!isempty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sp+1; i++) {
            printf("%d ", stack[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

My idea of solving this task was to make another *temp* stack and copy main *stack* into it, than use two *for* loops to compare all elements and inside that I used *if* statment to check if they are same or not, if they are not same I just pushed them into back into stack that was previously cleared, by this way I'm supposed to skip all duplicate elements but for some reason this code is not working properly it keeps *spamming* me "Full!" message.

```
void removeDuplicates() {
    int* temp = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    int temp_size = 10;
    int temp_sp = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sp + 1; i++) {
        temp[i] = stack[i];
    }
    temp_sp = sp;
    clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < temp_sp+1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < temp_sp+1; i++) {
            if (!(temp[i] == temp[j])) {
                push(temp[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is main function that I used to test out functions:

```
int main() {
    push(1);
    push(2);
    push(3);
    push(4);
    push(3);
    push(5);

    removeDuplicates();

    print();

    return 0;
}
```

If there is simpler way to solve this by using C++ (not `std::stack`), let me know.

Comment: Please decide whether you want to ask about C++ or C, and delete the tag you are not interested in.  (This code looks like C, and the fact you are suggesting `malloc` also suggests C. not C++.)

Comment: Are you required to define a stack like that in **C++**?... Because C++ has its own `std::stack` in the *STL*... Also pick only one language at a time since we here expect you to ask **only one question at a time**...

Comment: order of elements in stack should be maintained or not?

Comment: @Ruks - This is *clearly* an educational task, not production code.  Suggesting `std::stack` is not helpful.

Comment: Ruks - We are not allowed to use std::stack that's why we need to use implementation like this one. Marek R - Not defined but I guess it should work for an unsorted stack.

Comment: Is it C or C++? That's the first point.

Comment: Seems that you are treating the `stack` like an `array`. When removing duplicates from stack, remember you have to `pop` the duplicate element from `stack`.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's C or C++, if someone has better solution for C++ I would like to see it. Pop is going to remove only last element in stack, I was thinking of maybe rearranging stack and putting duplicate elements at the end and than poping them.

Comment: When you say "delete all duplicates", do you mean if there are two `42`s they should both be removed? Or if one is to remain, which one? This is a stack, so the sequence must be important.

Comment: @E.Đordan yes `pop` is going to remove only the last element and that simply means you have `pop` all the elements above the duplicate element before removing duplicate from `stack`. Also, can you specify whether the `stack` elements are in sorted order or not?

Comment: Your code still doesn't compile without warnings - I suggest you include `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this code that is supposed to work for normal array, but not sure if it's right for stack as we might using dynamic memory

Whether your code is correct for stacks is nothing to do with dynamic allocation, and everything to do with the interface of a stack. Do you know what that is? It's absolutely essential to solving your problem, and I don't see any hint that you either know how a stack behaves, or tried to research it.

Here you are, the [stack abstract datatype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)):

- preserves last-in first-out order
- allows you to push a new element onto the top of the stack
- allows you to pop the most recently pushed element (that wasn't already popped) from the top of the stack.

That's everything, and there is no random access (ie, `stack[j]` will never be a valid expression), so it is *obviously* impossible for the algorithm you showed to work.

If you don't have a stack implementation already - write one! You're going to need a stack to compile and test your algorithm anyway. The definitions you show describe the storage, but not the interface.

There are only two functions to code (plus the two to create and destroy a stack, and optionally one to query the size).

Now for the algorithm - you can only ever access the top element of a stack, so you need to think about what to with the elements you `pop` that *aren't* duplicates. They have to go somewhere, because you can't see below them while they're on your main stack, and you mustn't lose them.

---

Your edit shows you do have a stack datatype, sort of: it uses three global variables which you have to take care not to break, and you can't reuse any of the functions for your temporary stack, because they operate on those globals.

Even in C, I'd expect to see something like this (untested, un-compiled sample code based on yours above)

```
struct Stack {
    int size;
    int sp;
    int data[];
};

struct Stack* stack_create(int elements) {
    struct Stack *s = malloc(sizeof(*s) + elements * sizeof(int));
    s->size = elements;
    s->sp = -1;
    return s;
}

bool stack_isEmpty(struct Stack *s) { return s->sp == -1; }
bool stack_isFull(struct Stack *s) { return s->sp == s->size - 1; }
void stack_push(struct Stack *s, int x)
{
    assert(!stack_isFull(s));
    s->data[++s->sp] = x;
}
int stack_pop(struct Stack *s)
{
    assert(!stack_isEmpty(s));
    return s->data[(s->sp)--];
}
```

because then you can use the same operations on your main and temporary stacks.

If the `removeDuplicates` message is *supposed* to be implemented in terms of the stack abstraction, you need an algorithm you can implement in terms of `stack_push`, `stack_pop` etc.

If the `removeDuplicates` message is *supposed* to be an internal function operating directly on the stack implementation, rather than being implemented in terms of the stack abstraction - then your basic approach is probably OK (if very far from optimal), and you just need to learn to *debug* your code.

I still don't know which one of those is true (so I won't vote to re-open yet), but they are completely different questions.

Comment: if you look past the (slightly) harsh tone and remarks the advices here are actually very very good.

Comment: This is only true if the OP is supposed to work with a stack abstract data structure.  *I* think the OP is supposed to add a new function to a stack API which allows deduplication.

Comment: If that's true, it still suggests there should be an existing stack-like API though, right?

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems with your current code:

In the loop

```
for (k = j; k < size; k++)
{
    stack[k] = stack[k + 1];
}
```

you go out of bounds because you use `stack[k+1]`. How would you fix that?

But then after you have moved all the elements down by 1, the new `stack[j]` may be another duplicate of `stack[i]`. How would you fix that? You might consider using a `while` loop.

You use a global variable `size` which is the stack size. But there is also a variable `sp` that is the stack pointer and indicates the part of the stack in use. So instead of looping over `size` you should loop over `sp`.

Note what the stack pointer points at: the value `-1` means stack empty, so any other value points at the current value at the top of the stack. (This is important beause the other interpretation of the stack pointer is that it points at the next free element of the stack.)

This `sp` of course decreases with every duplicate you remove from the stack.